# PHP, WAMP - failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I'm testing a project with WAMP, but I had a problem when I upload a file and copy, it returns:

> failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in C:\wamp\www\

What can I do?

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if ( isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
    $nombre=$_SESSION['user'];
    $nombrefoto=$_FILES['foto']['name'];
    $ruta=$_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
    $destino = "http://localhost/usuarios/".$_SESSION['user'].".jpg";
    copy($ruta,$destino);
} else {

}

?>
```

Comment: You should use a local filename as the destination of `copy`, not a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a writable filesystem set as your copy destination ... this is probably what you mean.

```
$destino = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/usuarios/".$_SESSION['user'].".jpg";
copy($ruta,$destino);
```

Make sure that the usuarios directory in your document root exists and is writable by the web server.